# f2py compile fails: python27.dll File format not recognized

Tags: python, f2py

I have a number of fortran codes that I need to run through python.  As a first step, I'm trying a simple subroutine:

```
  subroutine multiply(a,b,n,c)
    double precision, intent(in) :: a(n), b(n)
    integer, intent(in) :: n
    double precision(out) :: c(n)
    integer :: i
    do i=1,n
     c(i)=a(i)*b(i)
    end do  
  end subroutine multiply
```

Then I'm trying to compile using f2py.py:
`f2py -c --fcompiler=gnu95 --compiler=mingw32 -m foo mult.f`

I get an error when looking for python27.dll: File format not recognized.
here's the output from the compiler:

```
C:\Users\Richard\Documents\Code\fortran>f2py -c --fcompiler=gnu95 --compiler=mingw32 -m foo mult.f
 running build
running config_cc
unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
running config_fc
unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
running build_src
build_src
building extension "foo" sources
f2py options: []
f2py:> c:\users\richard\appdata\local\temp\tmpxwldfw\src.win-amd64-2.7\foomodule.c
creating c:\users\richard\appdata\local\temp\tmpxwldfw
creating c:\users\richard\appdata\local\temp\tmpxwldfw\src.win-amd64-2.7
Reading fortran codes...
        Reading file 'mult.f' (format:fix,strict)
Post-processing...
        Block: foo
                        Block: multiply
Post-processing (stage 2)...
Building modules...
        Building module "foo"...
                Constructing wrapper function "multiply"...
                  multiply(a,b,c,[n])
        Wrote C/API module "foo" to file "c:\users\richard\appdata\local\temp\tmpxwldfw\src.win-amd64-2.7\foomodule.c"
  adding 'c:\users\richard\appdata\local\temp\tmpxwldfw\src.win-amd64-2.7\fortranobject.c' to sources.
  adding 'c:\users\richard\appdata\local\temp\tmpxwldfw\src.win-amd64-2.7' to include_dirs.
copying C:\Users\Richard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\src\fortranobject.c -> c:\users\richard\appdata\local\temp\tmpxwldfw\src.win-amd64-2.7
copying C:\Users\Richard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\src\fortranobject.h -> c:\users\richard\appdata\local\temp\tmpxwldfw\src.win-amd64-2.7
build_src: building npy-pkg config files
running build_ext
Looking for python27.dll
Building import library (arch=AMD64): "C:\Users\Richard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\libs\libpython27.a" (from C:\Users\Richard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\python27.dll)
**objdump.exe: C:\Users\Richard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\python27.dll: File format not recognized**
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Richard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\Scripts\f2py-script.py", line 24, in <module> main()

 ..removed details of stack trace, finally ending with

File "C:\Users\Richard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\mingw32ccompiler.py", line 399, in _build_import_library_amd64    generate_def(dll_file, def_file)
File "C:\Users\Richard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\mingw32ccompiler.py", line 278, in generate_def    raise ValueError("Symbol table not found")
ValueError: Symbol table not found
```

I'm really not sure what's causing this.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of python27.dll on your system?  It sounds like the wrong dll is being loaded at some point in the process.

Comment: I've found 2 versions of python27.dll, when I try to register the one listed in the compiler output, I get the error message: "The module 'C:\...\python27.dll was not loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found.  Make sure that C:\...\python27.dll is a valid DLL or OCV file and then try again."  Is there a way to check/fix/replace the dll file?

Comment: You'll probably need to look at your environment variables for PATH and PYTHONPATH.  You may also end up uninstalling / removing the conflicting versions.

Comment: Okay, I'll likely do that.  Unfortunately, more pressing issues have arisen, and I'll have to shelve this problem for a while.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The error is the same as the one mentioned here, "Method 3". See the OP's solution there

[Compile fortran module with f2py and Python 3.6 on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48826283/compile-fortran-module-with-f2py-and-python-3-6-on-windows-10?rq=1)