# Compile fortran module with f2py and Python 3.6 on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, anaconda, mingw, python-3.6, f2py

I'm trying (and failing) to compile a fortran module (specifically [igrf12.f](https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/IAGA/vmod/igrf12.f) from the BGS) using f2py and Python 3.6 on Windows 10. Python was installed using Anaconda 4.4.10.

**My setup:**

- Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Oct 15 2017,
  03:27:45) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
- Windows 10 Enterprise (version 1703)
- NumPy 1.14.0

I followed f2py directions from the [SciPy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/f2py/getting-started.html#the-smart-way) and a very [helpful guide](https://www.scivision.co/f2py-running-fortran-code-in-python-on-windows/) from Dr.Michael Hirsch. Dr.Hirsch has created the pyigrf12 module, but installation through pip failed for me, which is what initially sparked my interest in f2py.

I will outline a few of the methods I am using. Regardless of the method, I always begin by creating a *.pyf signature file using `f2py igrf12.f -m pyigrf12 -h igrf12.pyf` and adding intent(in/out) attributes appropriately.

- Method 1: Use C:\MinGW and `--compiler=mingw32`
- Method 2: Use C:\MinGW and `--compiler=msvc`
- Method 3: use anaconda version of mingw and `--compiler=mingw32`
- Method 4: use anaconda version of mingw and `--compiler=msvc`

**Method 1:**

For background, I have MinGW at C:\MinGW and I have added C:\MinGW\bin to my user Path. Unfortunately, I did not install this version of MinGW (I inherited this computer from a colleague), so I do not know where it was sourced. The gcc --version and gfortran --version is 5.3.0.

I run `f2py -c igrf12.pyf igrf12.f --compiler=mingw32`. This fails with this error message:

```
Building import library (arch=AMD64):
"C:\Users\Sholes\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\libs\libpython36.a" 
(from C:\Users\Sholes\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python36.dll)
    objdump.exe: C:\Users\Sholes\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python36.dll: File format not recognized

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sholes\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\\f2py.py", line 28, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Sholes\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\f2py2e.py", line 648, in main
    run_compile()
  File "C:\Users\Sholes\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\f2py2e.py", line 633, in run_compile
    setup(ext_modules=[ext])
  File "C:\Users\Sholes\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 169, in setup
    return old_setup(**new_attr)
  File "C:\Users\Sholes\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Users\Sholes\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\Sholes\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\Sholes\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\command\build.py", line 47, in run
    old_build.run(self)
  File "C:\Users\Sholes\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\Users\Sholes\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\Sholes\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\Sholes\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 117, in run
    force=self.force)
  File "C:\Users\Sholes\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 733, in new_compiler
    compiler = klass(None, dry_run, force)
  File "C:\Users\Sholes\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\mingw32ccompiler.py", line 104, in __init__
    build_import_library()
  File "C:\Users\Sholes\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\mingw32ccompiler.py", line 416, in build_import_library
    return _build_import_library_amd64()
  File "C:\Users\Sholes\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\mingw32ccompiler.py", line 472, in _build_import_library_amd64
    generate_def(dll_file, def_file)
  File "C:\Users\Sholes\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\mingw32ccompiler.py", line 302, in generate_def
    raise ValueError("Symbol table not found")
ValueError: Symbol table not found
```

**The issue seems to involve building libpython36.a from python36.dll**.

After a quick google search, a suggestion on a [github forum for pywafo](https://github.com/wafo-project/pywafo/issues/26) was to use the msvc compiler instead of mingw32, leading to Method 2.

**Method 2:**
For background, the files related to my msvc are being pulled from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\bin\HostX86\x64\`. Not sure if that's helpful.

I run `f2py -c igrf12.pyf igrf12.f --compiler=msvc`. This produces two files:

- `pyigrf12.cp36-win_amd64.pyd` in my current working directory and,
- `libigrf12.BMWM6WD5Y3O3UTOEQITBXCIICXVMBEZS.gfortran-win_amd64.dll` in `.\UNKNOWN\.libs\`

When I try to `import pyigrf12`, first I receive `ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.` Using Dependency Walker, I receive a lot of errors:

[image: f2py Dependency Walker Output]

but the most obvious one to address is related to the `libigrf12.BMWM6WD5Y3O3UTOEQITBXCIICXVMBEZS.gfortran-win_amd64.dll`. I move this libigrf12 dll file to my current working directory, alongside `pyigrf12.cp36-win_amd64.pyd`.

Now when I try `import pyigrf12`, I receive `ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.`. Some stackoverflow posts seem to indicate that this is a problem with a conflict between a 32-bit dll and 64-bit Python. **Can anyone offer insight into this?** After more searching, I decided to try to use the anaconda version of mingw and libpython.

**Method 3:**

I run `conda install mingw libpython`, and it installs mingw 4.7-1 and libpython 2.1-py36_0. I run `f2py -c igrf12.pyf igrf12.f --compiler=mingw32`, and it fails with the following error message:

```
Building msvcr library: 
"C:\Users\Sholes\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\libs\libvcruntime140.a" 
(from C:\Users\Sholes\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\vcruntime140.dll)
    objdump.exe: C:\Users\Sholes\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\vcruntime140.dll: File format not recognized
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Sholes\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\\f2py.py", line 28, in <module>
        main()
      File "C:\Users\Sholes\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\f2py2e.py", line 648, in main
        run_compile()
      File "C:\Users\Sholes\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\f2py2e.py", line 633, in run_compile
        setup(ext_modules=[ext])
      File "C:\Users\Sholes\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 169, in setup
        return old_setup(**new_attr)
      File "C:\Users\Sholes\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\Users\Sholes\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\Users\Sholes\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\Sholes\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\command\build.py", line 47, in run
        old_build.run(self)
      File "C:\Users\Sholes\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "C:\Users\Sholes\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Users\Sholes\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\Sholes\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 117, in run
        force=self.force)
      File "C:\Users\Sholes\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 733, in new_compiler
        compiler = klass(None, dry_run, force)
      File "C:\Users\Sholes\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\mingw32ccompiler.py", line 107, in __init__
        msvcr_success = build_msvcr_library()
      File "C:\Users\Sholes\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\mingw32ccompiler.py", line 399, in build_msvcr_library
        generate_def(dll_file, def_file)
      File "C:\Users\Sholes\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\mingw32ccompiler.py", line 302, in generate_def
        raise ValueError("Symbol table not found")
    ValueError: Symbol table not found
```

**Now the issue seems to relate to building libvcruntime140.a from vcruntime140.dll.** Once again the dll file format is not recognized by objdump.exe.

**Method 4:**

My final attempt was to run `f2py -c igrf12.pyf igrf12.f --compiler=msvc` with the anaconda version of mingw installed. For this case, gfortran failed with this error:

```
   C:\Users\Sholes\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\gfortran.bat -Wall -g -Wall -g -shared 
..\..\..\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpugo__0q9\Release\igrf12.o -Lc:\users\sholes\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\mingw\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.7.0 -LC:\Users\Sholes\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\libs -LC:\Users\Sholes\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\PCbuild\amd64 -o C:\Users\Sholes\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpugo__0q9\Release\extra-dll\libigrf12.75XJA5DX6DTO7YIZ7X6ZHJYTRDCCYQYR.gfortran-win_amd64.dll -Wl,--allow-multiple-definition -Wl,--output-def,C:\Users\Sholes\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpugo__0q9\Release\libigrf12.75XJA5DX6DTO7YIZ7X6ZHJYTRDCCYQYR.gfortran-win_amd64.def -Wl,--export-all-symbols -Wl,--enable-auto-import -static -mlong-double-64

gfortran.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-mlong-double-64'
```

At this point, I just want to know if it is possible to create fortran extensions with my set up and f2py. I don't have any background compiling C or fortran extensions on Windows, and based on all of the questions related to issues with Python 3.6 scipy and numpy installation on Windows, it seems like this is a common problem without a simple solution.

Any feedback or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Finally got this working.

**Short version:**

Make sure you use 64-bit compilers (triple check the build for mingw-w64) for 64-bit Python. Not as obvious as it sounds to an `f2py` newb on Windows.

**Long version:**

I uninstalled my existing copy of MinGW (I suspect it was a 32 bit version) and instead downloaded a specific 64-bit build of [mingw-w64 7.2.0 from sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/7.2.0/threads-posix/seh/), specifically `x86_64-7.2.0-release-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev1.7z`. [This stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38393755/mingw-w64-offline-installer) was useful.

I unzipped and copied the "mingw64" folder into my C: drive (`C:\mingw64`). I added `C:\mingw64\bin` to my user Path.

I uninstalled the anaconda version of MinGW with `conda uninstall mingw`. Note, this is only necessary if you've previously installed MinGW using `conda`.

Upon running `f2py -c igrf12.pyf igrf12.f --compiler=mingw32` (in same directory as igrf12.pyf, see [Scipy Documentation](https://numpy.org/devdocs/f2py/f2py.getting-started.html#the-smart-way) for how to generate *.pyf file), `pyigrf12.cp36-win_amd64.pyd` is created without any errors. I can finally `import pyigrf12` successfully and access the underlying Fortran subroutines (e.g. igrf12syn).

Note, I can also run `f2py -c igrf12.pyf igrf12.f --compiler=msvc` successfully, but then I have to manually copy and paste the `libigrf12....gfortran-win_amd64.dll` (generated in `.\UNKNOWN\.libs\`) into the same directory as `pyigrf12.cp36-win_amd64.pyd` to avoid `ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.` mentioned in **Method 2** of my question.

Just to re-iterate: **Make sure** `C:\mingw64\bin` **is added to your path!**

By the way, `f2py` was painless for me on macOS Sierra and Ubuntu. If the above still doesn't work for you, I recommend trying on Linux, macOS or Windows Subsystem for Linux.

Comment: Your answer helped me with my python installation of Darkflow.  My error was caused by c:\Rtools\mingw_32\bin\gcc.exe i.e. 32 bit compiler trying to do a 64 bit build.  Uninstalling Rtools worked.  Can't thank you enough.  Cheers.

Comment: Awesome, glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The top answer helps a lot. I would like to add some comments about the missing DLLs. A useful tool to help you find out which DLLs are missing is [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon). You only need to add a filter `python.exe` and track which DLLs are failed to load. For me, the following ones are missing:

- libgcc_s_seh-1.dll
- libgfortran-5.dll
- libquadmath-0.dll
- libwinpthread-1.dll

I just need to copy them from the `bin/`  directory of my MinGW toolchain to the same directory of `python.exe`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, in particular the: `ValueError: Symbol table not found`  of Method 3.

[dsholes' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48826283/compile-fortran-module-with-f2py-and-python-3-6-on-windows-10/48886966#48886966) was the solution, plus 2 minor points:

- uninstall all versions of minggw
- download mingw64  (in my case: `x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0` ), install it
- Add `mingw64/bin` to PATH
- Then the compilation with `f2py -c fortran_file.F90 -m module_name --compiler=mingw32`
   runs fine, and can be imported properly in Python: `import module_name`

However:

1. your modules should be compiled in the same windows partition as Mingw32 is installed. Else (mingw was under `C:\`, my project under `D:\`, I get the following error, due to Relative paths not being read from one partition to another: `f2py target file 'C:\\...' not generated`
2. the compiled file may still require some external librairies. In my case, the `libquadmath-0.dll` in mingw64\bin is needed and should remain in the PATH at all time. Else I get a the following error: `ImportError: DLL load failed:`. I ended up identifying these dll and copying them within my project.