# conda-forge recipe for python package with a fortran extension not working on appveyor

Tags: anaconda, conda, appveyor, miniconda, conda-build

I am trying to get a conda-build recipe to pass all the CI tests on conda-forge/staged-recipes. Here is a link to the [pull request](https://github.com/conda-forge/staged-recipes/pull/7002) The python package has a fortran extension and uses numpy.distutils in the [setup.py](https://github.com/mbakker7/timml/blob/master/setup.py) to build the extension. Circle CI for Linux, Travis-CI for OSX pass, but I cannot get Appveyor for Windows to work with the conda-build recipe.

When using Miniconda for the Appveyor build for [Windows](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/mbakker7/timml/branch/master) and Travis CI build for [OSX and Linux](https://travis-ci.org/mbakker7/timml) for the package repo everything works and the tests pass. I can also get the conda-build recipe to work locally on Windows and Linux, but as you can see from the pull request to conda-forge the tests do not pass for Windows using Appveyor.

The import test fails to load the fortran extension with `ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module cannot be found.` The extension module is copied to the site-packages directory, `copying build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\timml\besselaesnew.cp36-win_amd64.pyd C:\bld\timml_1541596078787\_h_env\Lib\site-packages\timml`, so I am stumped why it is not being found. I [read](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/is-a-pyd-file-the-same-as-a-dll.htm) about the differences between .pyd and dll, and tried `--compiler=mingw32` instead of `--compiler=msvc` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48826283/compile-fortran-module-with-f2py-and-python-3-6-on-windows-10). That still didn't work. I also added `zlib` to the host and run section, after reading [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/install.html) and that didn't help.

Any tips to get a conda-build recipe for python package with a fortran extension working on Appveyor would be greatly appreciated. The compiler args in the `setup.py` file for windows is copied below in case that matters.

`if os.name == "nt":
    compile_args = ["-static-libgcc", "-Wall", "-shared"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was with the difference between dll and .pyd files and the compiler specification. After looking at the conda-forge-pinning [conda_build_config.yaml](https://github.com/conda-forge/conda-forge-pinning-feedstock/blob/master/recipe/conda_build_config.yaml), the way to choose mingw instead of msvc is:

```
requirements:
  build:
    - {{ compiler('fortran') }}
    - {{ compiler('m2w64_c') }}  # [win]
    - {{ compiler('m2w64_fortran') }}  # [win]
```